# use multiple select queries to fetch data for grid view

Tags: asp.net, gridview, c#-3.0

In .net 2008

I want to bind data to a grid view using multiple select queries
the reason for this is i want data to come from multiple data 
and i have to to some processing on the data before displaying it in grid view

an example is (i dont have to actually do this)

I have two tables one with columns uid and uname named udata
other with columns uid and unum named uinfo
now the problem is i want to have uid uname and unum concatenated together by a complex operation and display it in grid view
that complex operation can only be done in C# and not in T-SQL

I am basically making a case that one single query cannot fetch the data

so how do i do this for grid view

Comment: forget the example, i just want to know how to execute 2 sql statements and combine the results of those two queries to populate the gridview

Comment: @Archit: You can go for LINQ and do the required operations to get a single data table and then bind it to the Grid View. Would be helpful, if you show the actual requirement.

Comment: ok i figured it out, using a single select statement only

Answer (score 0):

If a gridview can display it, then you cannot really make the case that "one single query cannot fetch the data".  UNION your various select statements, making sure datatypes of the columns align.  You also have access to concatenation operator on server, and various substring functions.

Comment: as i said i have to do some post processing on the data that is y i cannot use one select query to fetch data

Answer (score 0):

Loop through your DataTables and create another data table to bind to the grid view.

Comment: then the issue is how do i merge data from two dataset

Answer (score 0):

you either use `ADO.NET` to return `DataSet` with two `DataTable`s or just `join` or `union` the queries and put and identifier `column` like `QueryType` from `bit` type and use `union` and for the first query set `QueryType` to `0` and the second one to `1` then in the C# part just deferential between them but `QueryType`.

I prefer the `DataSet` with two tables

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code.

```
    <div>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sds_udata" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Local %>" 
            ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Local.ProviderName %>" 
            SelectCommand="select * from udata" 
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sds_uninfo" runat="server" 
            SelectCommand="select * from uinfo" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Local %>" 
            ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Local.ProviderName %>"></asp:SqlDataSource>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            DataSourceID="sds_udata" AutoGenerateEditButton="True" ShowFooter="True" 
            AutoGenerateDeleteButton="True" 
            DataKeyNames="uid">
            <Columns>                
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="User ID" >
                <itemtemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="uid" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("uid") %>'></asp:Label>
                </itemtemplate>
                <edititemtemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtuid" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("uid") %>' Width="98%" MaxLength="6" ></asp:TextBox>
                </edititemtemplate>
                <footertemplate>
                   <asp:TextBox ID="txtNewuid" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("uid") %>' Width="98%" MaxLength="6"></asp:TextBox>
                </footertemplate>
                <itemstyle width="80px" /> 
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="User Name" >
                <itemtemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="uname" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("uname") %>'></asp:Label>
                </itemtemplate>
                <edititemtemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtuname" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("uname") %>' Width="98%" MaxLength="6" ></asp:TextBox>

                </edititemtemplate>
                <footertemplate>
                   <asp:TextBox ID="txtNewuname" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("uname") %>' Width="98%" MaxLength="6" ></asp:TextBox>

                </footertemplate>
                <itemstyle width="80px" /> 
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Custom Field" >
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblLocation" runat="server" Text='<%# LookupCustomeField(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "uid"), DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "uname"), DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "unum")) %>'></asp:Label> 
                </ItemTemplate>                   
               <ItemStyle Width="25%" /> 
           </asp:TemplateField> 
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>


    protected string LookupCustomeField(object uid, object uname, object unum)
    {
        string strUid, strUname, strUnum, result;
        if ((string.IsNullOrEmpty(uid.ToString())) || (string.IsNullOrEmpty(uname.ToString())) ||(string.IsNullOrEmpty(unum.ToString())))
            return null;

        strUid = uid.ToString();
        strUname = uname.ToString();
        strUnum = unum.ToString();
        result = strUid+ strUname+strUnum;            
        return result;
    }
```